# Twilio's videoViewDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I am using twilio framework to develop video communicate. And based on Twilio's video quick start i modify some way of presenting TwilioVideoView.

I am using a class inheriting UIView class called "myView", and the class has an instance property of TVIVideoView. Then i conform "myView" to protocol of TVIVideoViewDelegate, wishing to get some callback but i fail 
to get callback even i can success show remote peer's video on myView.

According to the comment of TVIVideoView says:

> delegate An object implementing the `TVIVideoViewDelegate` protocol (often a UIViewController).

Does it means i cannot conform custom class to TVIVideoViewDelegate?

Here's myView class:

```
open class myView: UIView {
    private var tviVideoView: TVIVideoView?
    public var myViewDelegate: MyViewDelegate?

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    public init(frame: CGRect, myViewDelegate: MyViewDelegate? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.tviVideoView = TVIVideoView.init(frame: self.frame, delegate: self)
        self.myViewDelegate = myViewDelegate
        self.tviVideoView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tviVideoView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(self.tviVideoView!)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}

extension myView: TVIVideoViewDelegate {
    func videoView(_ view: TVIVideoView, videoDimensionsDidChange dimensions: CMVideoDimensions) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("dimensions: \(dimensions.width), \(dimensions.height)")
            self.myViewDelegate?.videoView(self, videoDimensionDidChange: dimensions)
        }
    }
}

public protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func videoView(_ view: UIView, videoDimensionDidChange dimensions: CMVideoDimensions)
}
```

Comment: The `TVIVideoViewDelegate` protocol is available here: https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-ios/docs/latest/Protocols/TVIVideoViewDelegate.html. Have you implemented all the methods?

Comment: I checked the header, the delegate functions seems be optional. Should i implement all the functions to be take effect?

Comment: Wait, that's probably ok. But you've implemented `videoView/videoDimensionsDidChange`, are the video dimensions changing and why? Are you making the video dimensions change externally somehow?

Comment: Yes, i rotated the remote device and it did called with original twilio quick start. But not on my version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:
I create a class inherit TVIVideoViewDelegate and assign it as TVIVideoView's delegate. And it work! But i still don't know why?

My code as below:

```
open class myView: UIView {
    private var tviVideoView: TVIVideoView?
    public var myViewDelegate: MyViewDelegate? {
        didSet {
            self.delegatorOfTVIView?.myViewDelegate = myViewDelegate
        }
    }

    var delegatorOfTVIView: DelegatorOfTVIVideoViewDelegate?

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    public init(frame: CGRect, myViewDelegate: MyViewDelegate? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegatorOfTVIView =  DelegatorOfTVIVideoViewDelegate(myDelegate: myViewDelegate)
        self.myViewDelegate = myViewDelegate
        self.tviVideoView = TVIVideoView.init(frame: self.frame, delegate: delegatorOfTVIView)

        self.tviVideoView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tviVideoView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(self.tviVideoView!)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}


public protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func videoView(_ view: UIView, videoDimensionDidChange dimensions: CMVideoDimensions)
}

class DelegatorOfTVIVideoViewDelegate: NSObject, TVIVideoViewDelegate {
    var myViewDelegate: MyViewDelegate?

    init(myDelegate: MyViewDelegate? = nil) {
        super.init()
        self.myViewDelegate = myDelegate
    }

    func videoView(_ view: TVIVideoView, videoDimensionsDidChange dimensions: CMVideoDimensions) {
        print("TVIVideoDelegate call dimension change")
        self.myViewDelegate?.videoView(view, videoDimensionDidChange: dimensions)
    }
}
```